# Add radio button input to textbox input and store it in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textbox where users can enter their name and 2 radio buttons, one for Mr. and one for Mrs. .

When the user hits the submit button I want a function to run that checks which radio button the user checked and add it to their name, then store it in a list.

For example lets say they enter their name as John and click the Mr. box. I want it to add Mr. to john and then store it in a list. So it would store Mr.John is a list.

Im at a loss as to how to do this, Heres what I've got so far:

```
var UserNames = []

var NameAdd = function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("nametextbox").value;
    UserNames.push("name");
}
```

If that code is correct it should take the input from the textbox and store it in a list.

Heres the css for the radio buttons:

```
#CheckBox1,#CheckBox2 { 
    float:left;
     margin: 600px 20px 20px 60px; 
     color: #b2aba4;

}
```

And heres the html:

```
<div id="CheckBox1"><input type="radio" Name="Mr."/>Mr.</div>
<div id="CheckBox2"><input type="radio" Name="Mrs."/>Mrs.</div>
```

Any help is appreciated im at a loss here. Ik that it should be a if/else statement but past that im clueless.

Comment: Why do you think the CSS is relevant?

Comment: `UserNames.push("name");` pushes a string with the value `name` into your array. Even if you stored the right stuff in your variable *name* it would have to be `UserNames.push(name);`.

Answer (score 3):

I would change your markup to this:

```
<div id="CheckBox1"><input type="radio" name="salutation" value="Mr." />Mr.</div>
<div id="CheckBox2"><input type="radio" name="salutation" value="Mrs." />Mrs.</div>
```

and you can then get the value with this JavaScript:

```
var salutation = document.querySelector('input[name = "salutation"]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it at Client side this may help you:

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/58kn66gu/)

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function()
{
    var curSex = $("input[type=radio]").val();
    var curName = $("input[type=text]").val();
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = "Hello" + " " + curSex + curName;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="CheckBox1"><input type="radio" Name="Mr." value="Mr." />Mr.</div>
<div id="CheckBox2"><input type="radio" Name="Mrs." value="Mrs." />Mrs.</div>

Enter Name : <input type="text" name="name" />

<button>Submit</button>

<p id="print"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="send" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" id ="userName" />
<div id="CheckBox1"><input  type="radio" id ="mr" value="Mr." Name="title"/>Mr.</div>
<div id="CheckBox2"><input type="radio" id ="mrs" value="Mrs." Name="title"/>Mrs.</div>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Submit"   onClick="getInfo(this.form);" />
</form>
<p id="info"></p>
```

**java script code**

```
function getInfo(form) {
var userName = document.getElementById("userName");
var mr = document.getElementById('mr');
var mrs = document.getElementById('mrs');
var data = [];
if (userName.value !== "") {
    if (mr.checked) {
        data.title = mr.value;
        mrs.checked = false;
    } else if (mrs.checked) {
        data.title = mrs.value;
        mr.checked = false;
    }
    data.name = userName.value;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Hello:" + data.title + " " + data.name;
}
//console.log(data);

}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadtarawneah/0qyuopxm/)